# Is there a quick way to add a 1,000 image links to a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, image, hyperlink, html-table

I have a folder with a 1,000 pictures and I want to add them to a table to be able to fetch them and display the images as row pic.

```
include("dbopen.php");
 $result = mysql_query("
  SELECT `item`, (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) AS `rank` FROM `rtgitems` 
ORDER BY (`totalrate` / `nrrates`) DESC LIMIT 10
");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{  
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['itempic'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['item'] . "</td>";  
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['rank'] . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>";  
 }  
echo "</table>";
```

How to add them and call the table with the links I would like them to be on a separate table and item and itempic are related.

item is the item name
and itempic is the item image stores as a link

Answer (score 1):

I would start by printing the file list to a text file

```
cd imagefolder
ls > images.txt
```

From then on you could build 1000 queries in your favourite text editor, or use PHP to explode the whole text by linebreaks, etc.